# Epson L3110 Print Quality

Tags: drivers, printing, epson, quality

I Have a working printer configured, I've Installed ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver)
But I cannot change the print quality, and this is a mandatory option, as prints are such a crap (for photos for example)

I think it's a driver issue, in Windows quality options are avaliable and the print is in such a good quality, but what can be done here?
This printer is capable of 5760 x 1440 dpi resolution and I can only use 300 dpi!

Another thing that worth to mention is that the printer is shared through CUPS, and I can print remotely from a Windows machine (Guest) with High Quality option!

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the same printer and also had issues with quality. I'm using a rasp pi as CUPS server to the local network and using the driver o (L130 that was the similar to me). It works ok for text files but anything complex with colors is a shame. I also had issues to use the Epson software for printing photos with that. Never worked. I'm here basically to grab more info about the same problem.